# how to call liquibase from java integration test?

Tags: spring-boot, liquibase

I have springboot app with oracle testcontainer. It works, I can connect to db and ran statements against it. Next step is to init db using liquibase.

There is [documentation](https://contribute.liquibase.com/extensions-integrations/directory/integration-docs/springboot/springboot) how you can use springboot to init db. If you follow it, it does literally nothing.

Then there is [liquibase api](https://docs.liquibase.com/workflows/liquibase-community/using-liquibase-java-api.html) which we can use, and if we use source code from link, there will be unimplemented methods I have no idea what they should do( ?? getDatabase() ??), reference to inexisting classes (DbUrlConnectionCommandStep), and there is no mention about which liquibase version is this sample for, so I really don't know what is wrong ...

Can anyone show me how to call liquibase update command from java(or give reference to good article/mwe)? It can be generic api, but springboot focused would be better.

Comment: I think the title is wrong. It seems you never got Spring Boot liquibase to work in the first place. Then integration tests won't work either. The question is unrelated to testing as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to init `db` with liquibase scripts:

Add gradle/maven dependency:

Gradle:

```
implementation 'org.liquibase:liquibase-core:4.24.0'
```

Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
    <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.24.0</version>
</dependency>
```

On `application.yml` configuration set next one parameter:

```
spring:
  liquibase:
    enabled: true
    change-log: classpath:db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml
```

Where `change-log` is the path to change-log file into `resources` folder of project.

Change-Log file: Create a `db.changelog-master.yaml` file into `resources->db->changelog` folders path

`db.changelog-master.yaml` file will contains next one information:

```
databaseChangeLog:
  - includeAll:
      path: liquibase/init
```

Here you have to declare path to `sql` files also it will be located to folders paths `resources->liquibase->init` and here into `init` folder you have to add `.sql` files.

And that is all.

P.S. If you are writing spring-boot integration tests it will automatically up the context and read/reread the `liquibase` sql files

Comment: Thanks, I was probably missing the enabled property. But can you please elaborate on that: "and read/reread the liquibase sql files"? Especially on that re-read word.

Comment: re-read I meant when you delete inserts from liquibase `changelog` table. Nothing more

Comment: delete inserts. Still not following. So tests started, db clean, liquibase ran initing db and filling changelog table with records. Now I'm delete them using custom statement (no idea why), what will happen?

Comment: I think you can find answer to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75104946/liquibase-keep-changes-from-script-but-remove-the-changelog-in-changelog-table), By the way  I think this topic `how liquibase work internally` you can find into documentation.

Comment: IIUC if I delete row from changelog, and then ran liquibase again, the given changeset will be reapplied since liquibase thinks it wasn't applied, sure. I just didn't understand how that would be part of testing flow and though that you are suggesting, that liquibase somehow tracks that table and will do I don't know what. If it's just this, then I understand. Thanks.